# SQL: Optimize a query that uses 3 LEFT OUTER JOINs on the same table

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, left-join

I have a sub query that needs optimization. It is joining on itemInventory 3 times with

> left outer joins

Is there a way to do this with UNIONs?... being that 3 columns get their data from each join, 'LastDate' I found it difficult to envision a query to replace this one that would be more efficient.

Here's the query:

```
select 
ii1.vendorno, 
ii1.Quantity1, 
ii3.date1, 
ii1.fgspecialpo, 
ii1.itemid,
ii1.LastDate as [LastDate1], 
ii2.LastDate as [LastDate2], 
ii3.LastDate as [LastDate3],
ii1.qtytype as [qtytyp], ii1.quantity2 as [qty2], ii2.Quantity1 as [itemsAddlQty], 
ii3.quantity1 as [Exp Qty]  
from iteminventory ii1      
    left outer join (select * from iteminventory where qtytype=11 ) ii2 on ii1.itemid=ii2.itemid and ii1.fgspecialpo=ii2.fgspecialpo and ii1.vendorno=ii2.vendorno      
    left outer join (select * from iteminventory where qtytype=1 ) ii3 on ii1.itemid=ii3.itemid and ii1.fgspecialpo=ii3.fgspecialpo and ii1.vendorno=ii3.vendorno
```

Answer (score 2):

UNION isn't going to help you here. A UNION is used to combine two result sets which is not what you have here. You can certainly simplify this to use joins instead of those subqueries. I suspect it won't make much difference in the actual execution plan though. If the performance is problematic we would need to see the table definition including indexes. Here is how you could convert this simply use joins.

```
SELECT ii1.vendorno
    , ii1.Quantity1
    , ii3.date1
    , ii1.fgspecialpo
    , ii1.itemid
    , ii1.LastDate AS [LastDate1]
    , ii2.LastDate AS [LastDate2]
    , ii3.LastDate AS [LastDate3]
    , ii1.qtytype AS [qtytyp]
    , ii1.quantity2 AS [qty2]
    , ii2.Quantity1 AS [itemsAddlQty]
    , ii3.quantity1 AS [Exp Qty]
FROM iteminventory ii1
LEFT OUTER JOIN iteminventory ii2 ON ii1.itemid = ii2.itemid
                                AND ii1.fgspecialpo = ii2.fgspecialpo
                                AND ii1.vendorno = ii2.vendorno
                                AND ii3.qtytype = 11
LEFT OUTER JOIN iteminventory ii3 ON ii1.itemid = ii3.itemid
                                AND ii1.fgspecialpo = ii3.fgspecialpo
                                AND ii1.vendorno = ii3.vendorno
                                AND ii3.qtytype = 1
```

Comment: @BhatiaAshish I misread your edit. You were correct in adding qtytype = 11.

Comment: I tried your way against the original and it performed poorly 'relative to the batch' at 78% vs 22% for the original. Have to keep searching ... Thanks though. Learned a little. And I can't share the table def... (doesn't matter anyway, we're not allowed to change the db)

Comment: I would be surprised if the execution for this and the way you did it originally would be very different. Most likely you need to improve indexing on this table before the performance is going to improve. But without those details it is anybody's guess.

Comment: I agree wholeheartedly... but my present position does not allow for changes in the db of any kind. We're a fulfillment company and index additions might slow some 5 million record nightly import that needs to batch out in a certain period of time. Besides a poorly normalized db made 15 years ago and copy/pasted for every new client... Thanks again.

Comment: Well with absolutely no changes allowed to the database there isn't anything you can do. There really isn't any changes you can make to the query itself to improve performance. Good luck!!!

Answer (score 2):

If I understood it correctly I think it's just matter of showing the data in different columns depending on the value of **qtytype** column. I don't think you require a join for this.

Check if this works for you:

```
SELECT 
    vendorno, 
    Quantity1, 
    CASE WHEN qtytype=1 THEN date1 ELSE NULL END as date1, 
    fgspecialpo,
    itemid,
    LastDate as [LastDate1], 
    CASE WHEN qtytype=11 THEN LastDate ELSE NULL END as [LastDate2], 
    CASE WHEN qtytype=1 THEN LastDate ELSE NULL END  as [LastDate3],
    qtytype as [qtytyp], 
    quantity2 as [qty2], 
    CASE WHEN qtytype=11 THEN Quantity1 ELSE NULL END as [itemsAddlQty], 
    CASE WHEN qtytype=1 THEN quantity1 ELSE NULL END as [Exp Qty]  
FROM iteminventory
```

Comment: I am not getting the same results as the first query with this. 'date1' is null for records where it should have a value. The OUTER from the original is bringing in more data then this new one. Wish I could paste a screenshot here showing the differences

Comment: @Beau if you have multiple rows for the join condition ii1.itemid=ii2.itemid and ii1.fgspecialpo=ii2.fgspecialpo and ii1.vendorno=ii2.vendorno then definitely you will get more rows than expected. Try adding DISTINCT clause to your original query which might remove the duplicate rows its pulling and result of my query and your query would be much closer. One more thing your query should not return more rows than your original table rows.

Comment: FYI, it's bringing in more column data not more rows. Some columns are null with the new way and the old (using outer joins) expressly brings in those other columns regardless if there'a a matching col in the left table... Thanks for the help, I think this one needs a rewrite or some other alteration to the indexes/schema. Now for the battle.